# How to use mkdirs in a thread safe manner in Java?

Tags: java, android, io, thread-safety, mkdir

After experiencing issues with mkdirs() and poking around the interwebs, I get the impression that there are thread safety issues with mkdirs().

Is there a way to ensure the directories are properly created when it is possible that multiple threads might be trying to create similar file structures?

Thanks

(In my case I will be using this on Android)

Comment: Could you provide references as to why you think `mkdirs()` is not thread safe?

Comment: Are there any details known (for J2SE and Android) under which circumstances this problem will appear with a high probability? Number of CPU cores, threads, OS, file-system? I am trying to raise this problem for testing purposes.

Comment: @TedHopp link is dead? can you re-link or explain what was it?

Comment: @cooton i agree `mkdirs()` doesn't seems to be synchronous!

Comment: @TedHopp Whether my understand regarding multiple threads trying to do `mkdir()` is **correct** or **not** that when multiple threads are running and wanted to create a dir lets say /data/abc. 1st thread come and execute the method `mkdir()` now while the mkdir() is in procress, the second thread come check if dir already exists and came to know that it doesn't and execute `mkdir()`.

Comment: I think using `synchronized-block` is the correct way to ensure thread-safety. like this `synchronized (this) 
  {dir.mkdirs());
  }`

Comment: @MuhammadBabar - I have no idea what happened to that post and I can't find a copy through a web search of the title (which is part of the url). Also, with it being 3+ years after the fact, I don't remember the specific points of the post. I did, however, run across [this discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.os.linux.development.apps/uVTkt0Iy2rU) which has a lot to say about the subject. It's about the Linux implementation of `mkdirs()`, but it almost certainly applies to the Java call in Android, since Android is based on a Linux kernel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I know this has been inactive for a while, but I thought perhaps there was a simple solution. The article you linked in the comments on the question seems to indicate that the only problem is directories *not* being created. The solution there was to do this:

```
if (!f.mkdirs()) {
    f.mkdirs();
}
```

However, that seems inefficient and can still have problems. So, why not simply do this:

```
while (!f.mkdirs()) {}
```

Simple, but it works.

EDIT: After thinking a bit, that example may lag to oblivion and could cause thread lock. So, this might be a better idea:

```
while (!f.mkdirs()) { Thread.yield(); }
```

Of course, that would only be recommended if you're in a thread that could cause thread lock, and as long as it's not a high-priority situation. Just putting this out there.

Comment: ...and really, really hope that this never gets run in a situation where mkdirs() fails for real reasons, like permissions issues or a badly formatted directory name.

Comment: @smackfu Good point. Perhaps it would be best to try a certain number of times, then display an error message.

Comment: I was having the exact problem and unfortunately nothing of the above worked for me but this worked `while(!dir.mkdirs())
  { 
   if(dir.isDirectory())
   {
    break;
   }
   
  }`

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure if Android supports the concurrent package but here is my take:

```
private static Lock fsLock = new ReentrantLock();

private void mkdir( File dir ) throws FileNotFoundException {

    if( dir.exists() ) {
        return;
    }

    fsLock.lock();
    try {
        if( !dir.exists() ) {
            log.info( "Creating directory {}", dir.getAbsolutePath() );
            if( !dir.mkdirs() ) {
                throw new FileNotFoundException( "Can't create directory " + dir.getAbsolutePath() );
            }
        }
    } finally {
        fsLock.unlock();
    }
}
```

The method returns early if the directory already exists. If it doesn't exist, only one thread will try to create it.

Comment: This is great.  This fixed my issue I had with mutliple threads attempting to create the same directory.  Not on Android but in regular Java 5 application.

Comment: Yes, this is harder than it looks.

Answer (score 3):

Do all your directory creation in a worker thread that serializes everything. You can use a `Looper` and a `Handler` to make it easy to post `Runnables` that call mkdirs to your worker thread. When you're done making directories, you can call Looper.quit() to end the thread after it processes the last posted `Runnable`. The [documentation for `Looper`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Looper.html) has sample code that shows how near to trivial this is to do.

Answer (score 2):

One possible solution would be a MkDirService (illustrated below) that guarantees only one instance and runs in it's own thread. Making use of BlockingQueue.

First the Service:

```
package mkdir;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue;

public class MkDirService extends Thread {

    private static MkDirService service;
    private BlockingQueue<File> pendingDirs = new LinkedBlockingQueue<File>();
    private boolean run = true;

    private MkDirService() {
    }

    public synchronized static MkDirService getService() {
        if (service == null) {
            service = new MkDirService();
            new Thread(service).start();
        }
        return service;
    }

    public void makeDir(File dir) {
        pendingDirs.add(dir);
    }

    public void shutdown() {
        run = false;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (run || !pendingDirs.isEmpty()) {
            File curDir = null;
            try {
                curDir = pendingDirs.take();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            if (curDir != null && !curDir.exists()) {
                curDir.mkdir();
                System.out.println("Made: " + curDir.getAbsolutePath());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The the Test:

```
package mkdir;

import java.io.File;

public class MkDirServiceTest {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MkDirService mdServ = MkDirService.getService();
        mdServ.makeDir(new File("test1"));
        mdServ.makeDir(new File("test1/test2"));
        mdServ.makeDir(new File("test1/test3"));
        mdServ.shutdown();

    }
}
```

Comment: I would welcome any corrections to my example, I'm sure there are some better ways to do it, and would consider this a great learning opportunity.

Answer (score 1):

Eaven if this thread is a bit older I wonder if there is somethink wrong with the following solution:

```
package service;

import java.io.File;

public class FileService {

    public static synchronized boolean mkdirs( File dir ) {
        return dir.mkdirs();
    }
}
```