# Creating directory Structure in a UNC path with java

Tags: java, directory, timeout, samba, unc

I'm trying to Create a directory structure with java, in a remote UNC location.
java is running in a linux machine and the windows network path is mapped with SAMBA server.

Issue is :

When creating the directories it creates the first directory : OK

Try to create the first sub directory inside the first directory : FAILS

Because it takes some time (nearly 2 seconds) to show up the first directory through samba.
This could be due to the slowness of the network (but it's unavoidable   )

If i execute the same code step by step (debugging) it works normally and create the directory structure.

Please help me. 
I need some mechanism which will wait java mkdir() function until the initially created directory 
get showed up in the UNC path.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5189534/how-to-use-mkdirs-in-a-thread-safe-manner-in-java